# Cannot download file using webclient

Tags: c#, webclient

I try to download a file that is available from a link like this..

```
https://xxxxx.xxx/ff?fid=123.456
```

If I download it using a webbrowser it works but not when I use this code..

```
            try
        {
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.DownloadFile(fileUri, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\donload\\test.xlsx");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log.Error..
        }
```

When I do that I get a "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." How can I download the file, and also save it using the name returned from the url?

Comment: If you browse the same url in Browser, are you able to download the file?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: Can you share the real url if it's allowed for you? When you browse the url does it redirect to somewhere before starting the download? Do you need to login before you can download the file

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share the url. And as far as I can tell there is no redirection when accessing that url. it start to download the file immediately.

Comment: Well in that case, we can only guess the issue. 1. URL is not correct 2. Server is looking for something in request which you are not passing that's why server is return 404 3. Service is looking for some header value

Comment: Hmm, the url is correct

Comment: According to Fiddler i can see this.. RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)
--------------
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: That information isn't that helpful.  Please share with us the request/response headers you get from Fiddler when requested by your browser.

Comment: You can try to add agent name as your browser does:
wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

Comment: Thanks Viliam that worked, now I just have to retrieve the original filename from the response header